# AutoMapper : Copy IList<> to IList<>

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an `IList<AdminVAT>` and I'd like to copy this collection to `IList<AdminVATDto>` collection

I tried this :

```
IList<AdminVAT> listAdminVAT = new AdministrationService(session).ListDecimal<AdminVAT>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IList<AdminVAT>, List<AdminVATDTO>>();
var res = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<AdminVAT>, IList<AdminVATDTO>>(listAdminVAT);
```

I receive this exception  :

> Trying to map System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[AdminVAT, eSIT.GC.DataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[AdminVATDTO, eSIT.GC.WebUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

Thanks.

**Update1**

```
public class AdminVAT : IAdminDecimal
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Code { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Value { get; set; }
}
public class AdminVATDTO : AdminVAT
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public override decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I still have 5 decimal in my dropdown list ...

Controller :

```
IList<AdminVAT> listAdminVAT = new AdministrationService(session).ListDecimal<AdminVAT>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<AdminVAT, AdminVATDTO>();
model.ListVAT = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<AdminVAT>, IList<AdminVATDTO>>(listAdminVAT);
```

HTML :

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddVAT", new SelectList(Model.ListVAT, "Id", "Value", Model.Estimation.AdminVAT))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Define the mapping only between the simple types as explained in the [documentation](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays):

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<AdminVAT, AdminVATDTO>();
```

Then you will be able to convert between lists, collections, enumerables of those types:

```
IList<AdminVATDTO> res = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<AdminVAT>, IList<AdminVATDTO>>(listAdminVAT);
```

Comment: I tried this I think. The type of res is " IList<IList<AdminVAT>, IList<AdminVATDTO>>", need IList<AdminVATDTO>

Comment: @Kris-I, you must have tried something else. The type of `res` as shown in my example is `IList<AdminVATDTO>`. I've updated my answer to make this more clear instead of using `var`.

Comment: @Darin You are right, CodeRush when I do a "Delcare variable" give me : IList<IList<AdminVAT>, IList<AdminVATDTO>>

Comment: @Darin, still have a problem with this MVC see update 1 (coming soon)

Comment: @Kris-I, that's a totally different question. Maybe it would be better to close this thread and ask a new question. All I can tell you is that you are using AutoMapper wrongly. It is not supposed to be used like this between objects deriving one from the other. Use AutoMapper to map between types that do not have inheritance. Why `AdminVATDTO` derives from `AdminVAT`? Is this `AdminVATDTO` actually supposed to be a view model? It seems so because I see that you are trying to use some formatting on it. If it is it absolutely should not derive from your model but define a separate class.

Comment: @Darin I use Automapper like this in some other case and that's work.... but I'm gooing to create a new question in the coming minutes.

Comment: @Kris-I, well then I am afraid that you are using AutoMapper not the way it was supposed to be used.

Comment: This actually answered my question. NOTE: you NEVER need to create a map from List to List only the type in the generic arg. If you do, then you will get a Castle IList'1 proxy class which won't work

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, but from some reason the first object is copied from the source and then duplicated throughout the destination IList.  Does anyone have any ideas on what could be the problem?  I am using the same methodology as outlined as a solution above.